# Why moving image after hover - chrome only

Tags: css

moving image after hover

with chrome only!

see my page in google chrome browser: http://qass.im/teeny/

now hover all images..

Why moving image after hover?

```
.pin img{
width: 100%;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
display:block;
opacity:0.5;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.pin img:hover{
 opacity:1;
 }
```

thanks.

Comment: add more of a description in your actual question please

Comment: chrome here nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

Because of differ in image resizing algorithms (btw on my machine image center is "moved" in firefox), but not in chrome) - try to use an image of exact size you use in column 258x181px - in that case it wouldn't be resized by a browser and an effect of moving will dissappear.

Comment: What is the solution then?